# Pre Populated Values (Date,Text Area) in Lightning by visualforce url

Tags: visualforce, javascript, lightning, urlhacking, redirect

Hi everyone I have visual force page if user click proceed then I have to redirect to order object with some pre-populating values.

I used `sforce.one.createRecord` it works for string field but it doesn't work for `date field` so I am not able to pass `EffectiveDate`. I am not able to pass `textarea field` as well if it is entered in multiple lines but for single line it is passing.

I have salesforce date format as `DD/MM/YYYY` so I converted date to this format in javascript but it shows error while creating record. Kindly suggest how to pass date in this format.

```
    <script>

function GenerateOrder(){

 var d = new Date();               
 var day = d.getDate();           
 var monthIndex = d.getMonth()+1;          
 var year = d.getFullYear();

 var todaydate=day + '/' + monthIndex + '/' + year;

 var defaultValues = { 
                             'Cart_No__c' : '{!Crt.Id}',
                             'AccountId' : '{!Crt.Account__c}',
                             'EffectiveDate' : todaydate
                       };

  sforce.one.createRecord("Order", null, defaultValues);
}
   </script>
```

Comment: I don't see how this question is different than the last one you asked. What about this question is different? What did the duplicate fail to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation on [`force:createRecord`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_createRecord.htm):

> Prepopulating rich text fields is unsupported. It might work for simple values, but the internal format of rich text fields is undocumented, so setting complex values that include formatting is problematic. Use at your own risk.
>
> Date and time field values must use the ISO 8601 format. For example:
>
> - Date: 2017-07-18
> - Datetime: 2017-07-18T03:00:00Z
>
> Note:
>
> While the create record panel presents datetime values in the user’s local time, you must convert datetime values to UTC to pre-populate the field.

Meaning you will likely be unable to set your rich text field, and you will need to modify your date formatting to `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYY-MM-DDTMM:SS:mmZ`, as appropriate.

Comment: I am not able to pass date as well as text area that's why I posted new question but now I am able to know that the format doesn't support and it is not possible to pass however that solved my problem for passing a String field.